# Perl Spreadsheet::WriteExcel мистика

Tags: perl

Всем привет.
В скрипте есть две функции

```
    sub f1 {
        my($excel1) = @_;

        if ($excel1 eq "excel1") {

        # Create a new Excel workbook
        my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("reports/report1_$z_period_from-$z_period_on.xls");
        $workbook->compatibility_mode();

        # Add a worksheet
        $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

        #  Add and define a format
        $format = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format
        $format_digit = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format

        $format->set_bold();
        $format->set_color('red');
        $format->set_align('center');

       # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
        $worksheet->merge_range('A1:Q1', "ТЕКСТ от $Current_Date", $format);

...
        $worksheet->write($row, $col, $_);
    }

    sub f2 {
        my($excel2) = @_;

        if ($excel2 eq "excel2") {

        # Create a new Excel workbook
        my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("reports/report2_$z_period_from-$z_period_on.xls");
        $workbook->compatibility_mode();

        # Add a worksheet
        $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

        #  Add and define a format
        $format = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format
        $format_digit = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format

        $format->set_bold();
        $format->set_color('red');
        $format->set_align('center');

        # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
        $worksheet->merge_range('A1:Q1', "ТЕКСТ от $Current_Date", $format);

...
        $worksheet->write($row, $col, $_);
    }
```

Две совершенно одинаковые функции. Но первая работает, а вторая выдает xls-файл 0 байт. Функции выводят отчеты. Изначально вызываются  на начальной странице скрипта, которую он выдает. Есть кнопка "Выгрузить в Ексель", по ней вызывается эта же функция но с передачей параметра "excel1" или "excel2", после чего помимо вывода на экран формируется ексель-файл, затем выдается пользователю:

```
$path = "http://my site/reports/report2_$z_period_from-$z_period_on.xls";
$out_web = qq~ 
<script language="JavaScript">
window.open('$path');
</script>
~;
print $out_web;
```

Где же собака зарылась?

Comment: У меня только одно объяснение - `$excel2` равна не тому, чему Вы ожидаете.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но Perl можно отлаживать, даже если это веб... Ну и да, лог входных параметров тоже не помешал бы.